# C pointers - Reading values from absolute addresses vs AddressOf operator (&)

Tags: c, pointers, memory

If I did not compile the code I'd say that **1** and **2** give the same result as both of them have an *int* pointer *p* pointing to variable *age*. Dereferencing *age* in both **1** and **2** should give the same result. I also understand that **3** will just give me the first byte of variable *age* as it's of type *char*. I can't explain why **1** and **2** give different results and why **2** and **3** give the same result.

**1**

```
int age = 20;
int* p = (int *)0x66FC9C;
printf("You're : %d\n", *p );
```

**2**

```
int age = 20;
int *p = &age;
printf("You're : %d\n", *p );
```

**3**

```
int age = 20;
char* p = (char *)0x66FC9C;
printf("You're %d\n", *p );
```

---

*Follow-up*

It's weird because when I do :

```
int age1 = 20;
int age2 = 19;
int* p = &age2;
printf("You're %d  %d  %d  %d\n", *p, *(p+1), &age1, &age2 );
```

[image]

and I actually *print* the addresses I always get the *p+1* right (meaning I can predict the address) but if I do :

```
int age1 = 20;
int age2 = 19;
int* p = &age2;
printf("You're %d  %d\n", *p, *(p+1)  );
```

[image]

I can never guess it. It's like C knows is being watched... *cough cough double slit experiment*

Comment: You realize that the address of a variable will be different every time you run the program?

Comment: @Rotem, *may* be different, not will.

Comment: Ari, why do you think that `0x66FC9C` is the address of `age`?

Comment: @paxdiablo To speak more relevantly, OP can not assume that `0x66FC9C` contains the variable they declared.

Comment: You can't be sure that `age` will be at address 0x66FC9C. It might not even be at *any* address, if the compiler decides to optimize out the variable or put it in a CPU register.

Comment: @interjay, I would have stated that your comment is for 1 and 3 only. Since, in 2, you take the address of it, the compiler *must* have it at an address.

Comment: I've added the reason why sometimes the address is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cheat the compiler, and it looks to be smarter than you...

More seriously, except if you really know the internals of a compiler, never try to guess how it will translate your source. Typically in your last example, a compiler can easily see that the `age1` variable is never used (at least never in a conformant way). So it can optimize it out. If you really want to better understand what happens here, you will have to ask the compiler to produce the assembly language that it has internally generated, and read it. You will see whether a variable has been optimized out (because it is not generated), or whether it was not consecutive to the other variable.

And anyway, it is nice to try to better understand what a compiler does, but please **never** do that in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Who do you know that the address of `age` is 0x66FC9C? If it's not then you will not be guaranteed the same result in 1 and 2. Equivalent reasoning can be given to 2 and 3.